# Непонятный name и id в html

Tags: html, html5

Что это за name и id в html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="c[country]" id="c[country]">
```

Как такие названии образовались и в каких случаях применяется?

Comment: Каким образом у вас это "образовалось", знаете ответ только вы. Вот информация по атрибуту name: http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/name идендификатор используется для получения объекта данного элемента в js и(или) привязка css свойств

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` отвечает за название элемента в форме, может быть представлен в массиве однородных элементов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
`$_POST`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`id` сделан как и `name`, видимо для удобства. Сомнительное удобство, на мой взгляд, но кому как.

Comment: 1) У вас то ли опечатка, или ошибка — `id="c[country]"` два раза повторяется, а повторять их нельзя. 2) Про допустимые символы в id у вас информация устаревшая — в HTML5 id может состоять из любых (вообще любых, даже русских или арабских) символов, кроме пробела — `c[country]` вполне правильный.

Comment: 1) Не очепятка, раз не годный `id`, то и вырезать/менять было лень, не его же демонстрирую. 2) Хм, можно ману? Хром и лиса у меня отказались такой `id` находить.

Comment: Ну мана это [сама спецификация](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute))

Comment: Хром и лиса у меня такие айдишники успешно находят: https://jsfiddle.net/qn57sw4b/ Попробую предположить, что вы пытались в `querySelector` или вообще jQuery, но они принимают CSS-селекторы — а такой айдишник в CSS в сыром виде юзать действительно не получится.

Comment: Гугл подсказал, что для querySelector айдишник можно экранировать и тоже заработает: https://jsfiddle.net/nv7vrozc/

Comment: @andreymal, хах, вот живёшь спокойно, не извращаешься с `id` и знать не узнаешь что их теперь, почему-то, можно так извращать. Мне и старой версии через голову хватало, дальше что - <див™> в разметку введут? Но благодарю за просвещение, сейчас пост поправлю.

Answer (score 3):

Такие вещи используются в Rails приложениях.
Дело в том, что при отправке формы (POST запросом) отправляется массив данных (params[]), а внутри этого массива зачастую лежит еще один массив именно с полями, передаваемыми приложению. То есть, чтобы в дальнейшем Rails мог получить доступ к переданным параметрам, атрибут name указывается именно так.

Вполне вероятно, что это именно ваш случай.